# Mocking the service that is tested or test an instance

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I ended up in a discussion with one of our my colleagues about how to setup a unit-test for testing a service class.

When setting up the test case one of us suggests mocking the actual class that we are testing, while the other prefers to make an instance of the class  and only mocking the dependencies.

So let's say we are testing `SomeService`

One solution would be to mock the actual service and test the mock:

```
$firstDependency  = //create mock for first dependency
$secondDependency = //create mock for second dependency
$this->someService = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeService::class)
     ->setMethods(null)
     ->setConstructorArgs(array($firstDependency, $secondDependency))
     ->getMock();

// continue testing $this->someService which is a mock
```

The other solution would be to test the instance of the service and only mocking the dependencies:

```
$firstDependency  = //create mock for first dependency
$secondDependency = //create mock for second dependency
$this->someService= new SomeService($firstDependency, $secondDependency);

// continue testing $this->someService which is direct instance of SomeService
```

Which of these solutions is considered best practice?

Answers preferably with some reference to official php-unit documentation or other reliable sources.

Comment: if don't really need mock to test - don't create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't mock class under test](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-stub-the-system-under-test). Not exactly *php-unit documentation*, yet all the points are still valid. Mocking the SUT you end up testing the mock, not the actual class that will be used in production.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of unit testing is to test behaviour. Mocking the object you want to test actually means you are testing 'faked' behaviour. What's the point of testing the behaviour that was predefined?

Answer (score 0):

In case of testing an abstract class creating a mock is considered good practice:

```
class AbstractClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * Service under test in this case an abstract class
     */
    $this->sut;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->sut = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('My\Abstract\Class');
    }

    public function testMyAbstractClass()
    {
        $this->sut // do your test
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not not really mocking as it sounds or looks to be. let's say you have a fully implemeted class that is still defined as abstract. In this case `getMockForAbstractClass` is just a workaround to get an instance, you are not faking it. This just saves you some time for typing to derive a dummy class from abstract one and use it in the testcase.

Comment: Mocking an abstract class will still add the mock magic into the abstract methods, and you'd need to add something there. If this is still useful probably depends on the amount and scope of abstract methods, but I would always try to test the real implementations - after all, THEY have to work correctly with everything, all the time. As a side note, avoid abstract classes, use composition to separate common code, and inject that as a dependency. Abstract classes have the tendency to also require testing protected or private methods, which is considered a code smell.